# Starting independent batch files through ssh and process ownership

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssh

I've used batch files for many things in the past... but I've always had this problem. I'm sorry if this is a repeat question, I'm not entirely sure I know how to phrase it for searching purposes. The problem is this:

1) Batch file starts some process. 
2) command window closed by user. 
3) process started by batch file ends.

I imagine this is due to the fact that the started process is "called" by the batch file, and is thus it's child. Specifically what I'm trying to do is login to a server through ssh, run a batch file located on that server which then starts a java program. I need the batch to either stay open, or allow the java program to own itself somehow. That way, when I leave the SSH session, the program will continue to run. Any ideas how I can do this?

I'm running a windows XP x64 server with MobaSSH.

Comment: Windows does not automatically kill child processes when the parent process exits, so this is probably something the SSH server is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) tools from sysinternals.

Some possible helpful commands:

1. [at](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565)
2. [schtasks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490996.aspx)
3. [sc](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192)
4. [wmic](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx)

I'm not sure that any of the above commands will be of any help, but I think they're worth checking out.

Comment: I appreciate the input... but I'm looking for something more secure and which allows the use of the already installed SSH shell access. EDIT: +1 upvote for a workable solution

Comment: @impyre: I suggest you SSH into the server to run the batch file, but use psexec in the batch file to launch Java.  There are no security issues that I'm aware of when using psexec to launch software on the local host.

Comment: @impyre - Do you ended up using `psexec` or any of the other commands?

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear, but looks like what you are looking for is a way to "detach" the script from the terminal so that it will continue to run even when the terminal is closed.

You can do:

```
nohup <your-script> &
```

Or:

```
<your-script> &
disown
```

Comment: that does sound like what I'm trying to do... but in windows shell

Comment: Ah sorry, missed the Windows part

Comment: I appreciate any input, and I thank you for taking the time to make a suggestion :)